# Simple Cartesian coordinate calculator

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to subtract the coordinates of 2 vectors but I'm a beginner who can't figure out the OOP code I need. This is what I have so far.

```
public class practice {

    public static class vector{
        int a;
        int b;
        public vector(int a, int b){
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
        public String coordinate(int x, int y){
            x = this.a - a;
            y = this.b - b;
            return x + " " + y;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        vector vec1 = new vector(2,3);
        vector vec2 = new vector(3,4);

        vector.coordinate?

    }
}
```

How can I subtract the ints from the 2 vector objects?

Comment: Quick question, what are you trying to do in the `coordinate` method?

Comment: you mean vec1-vec2 from the above example?

Comment: A general good practice is to have the first letter in the class names Capitalized. In your case, the class name should be `Practice` and `Vector`. But be careful while using the name `Vector`, remember to specify the right namespace

Comment: @Neil, is my answers not helpful to you?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done here some basic example which will allow you to subtract one vector from another one.

```
package com.test;

public class Vector {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Vector(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    /**
     * @return the x
     */
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    /**
     * @return the y
     */
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    // if you don't want to create new vector and subtract from it self, then return type of this method would be void only.
    public Vector subtract(Vector other) {
        return new Vector(this.x - other.x, this.y - other.y);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.x + " : "+ this.y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector vector1 = new Vector(10, 10);
        Vector vector2 = new Vector(5, 5);
        Vector vector3 = vector1.subtract(vector2); 
        System.out.println(vector3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not recommended.

Comment: You might wanna correct your `subtract` method. You have specified the variables as `private` and you are trying accessing it directly. Change it to the corresponding `getters` may be?

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want to call the `coordinate` method from `vec1` using data from `vec2`.
if so this is one way of doing it:

```
System.out.println(vec1.coordinate(vec2.a,vec2.b));
```

in this case you also need to change your coordinate method to:

```
    public String coordinate(int x, int y){
        x = this.a - x;
        y = this.b - y;
        return x + " " + y;
    }
```

Comment: Also, it should be `x = this.a - x` instead of `x = this.a - a`

Comment: Going by his definition of `coordinate`, I dont think it is doing what he wants it to do.

Comment: @tobias_k yeah just realized the method is wrong as well.

Comment: @Rakesh a good point mate, maybe he just wants distance instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method `XsubtractY` for which you input two vectors, then inside it gets each vectors a and b and subtracts them from each other to return your new vector. As follows:

```
public class practice {

public static class vector{
    int a;
    int b;
    public vector(int a, int b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public static vector XsubtractY(vector x, vector y){
        vector newVector = new vector(x.a-y.a, x.b - y.b);
        return newVector;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    vector vec1 = new vector(2,3);
    vector vec2 = new vector(3,4);
    vector newVector = vector.XsubtractY(vec1, vec2);
    System.out.println("New vector a: " + String.valueOf(newVector.a));
    /* New vector a: -1 */
    System.out.println("New vector b: " + String.valueOf(newVector.b));
    /* New vector b: -1 */

}
}
```

The new vector becomes (-1,-1)